# Formatting a search url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm rebuilding my site and want to change the urls - i need to let the search engines know so i'll be using 301 redirects.

my page is located at http://site.com/search.php

i want to use this url

```
http://site.com/search?s=foo&bar=bat&so+on&so+forth
```

my rewriteCond is

```
RewriteRule !^search search.php [R=301,L]
```

I'm getting a 404. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you can't use negation on the RewriteRule directly, what do you want to do? redirect the php to the non php version?

Comment: Redirect /search/ to search.php - basically, I want to remove .php from the URI and not have a trailing slash before the ?. I know how to do that, but what I've been using breaks when I add the 301 - so i need to get something working that has a 301.

Comment: let me know if my answer works for u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try, it should remove the `.php` and redirect to `search` and show the content of the `php`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.*)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

On the first rule we are checking the request to see if there is any `.php` present, if so we redirect it to the URL without the `.php`.

`(.*)` will capture anything before `.php` and the flag `QSA` will ensure the query string is appended to it.

`^([^/]+)/?$` this will match anything not a `/` until we find a `/` or hit the end.

So if we access `domain.com/index` it will capture index and redirect to index.php internally.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you. :) Could you please give me a little understanding of what's happening so I don't mess things up when adding future rules?

Comment: @Tim let me know if that is good enough or if there is a specific part you don't understand.

Comment: it's a thing of beauty. The explanation is perfect, thank you. :)